# Issue with Spinner Components in PrimeFaces 10.0.8: Not Automatically Tabbing to Next Field

Tags: primefaces

I'm experiencing an issue with the spinner components in PrimeFaces 10.0.8 on my web page. The problem is that once these elements have focus, pressing the Tab key doesn't automatically move to the next field.

I've even tried the example provided on the official PrimeFaces website for the spinner component, and the error persists. Here is the example code I tried:

```html
 <h:form>
        <div class="ui-fluid formgrid grid">
            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Basic Spinner"/>
                <p:spinner id="basic" value="#{spinnerView.number1}"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Step Factor"/>
                <p:spinner id="step" value="#{spinnerView.number2}" stepFactor="0.25"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Min/Max"/>
                <p:spinner id="minMax" value="#{spinnerView.number3}" min="0" max="100"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Rotate"/>
                <p:spinner id="rotate" value="#{spinnerView.number6}" min="0" max="10" rotate="true"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Rotate + No Wheel"/>
                <p:spinner id="rotateNoWheel" value="#{spinnerView.number6}" min="0" max="10" rotate="true" modifyValueOnWheel="false"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Rounded"/>
                <p:spinner id="rounded" value="#{spinnerView.number7}" min="0" max="55" stepFactor="5" round="true"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Prefix"/>
                <p:spinner id="prefix" value="#{spinnerView.number4}" prefix="$" min="0"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Horizontal"/>
                <p:spinner id="horizontal" value="#{spinnerView.number8}" buttons="horizontal" />
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Horizontal after"/>
                <p:spinner id="horizontalAfter" value="#{spinnerView.number9}" buttons="horizontal-after"
                           upButtonStyleClass="ui-button-success" downButtonStyleClass="ui-button-danger"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-fluid formgrid grid">
            <div class="field col-12 md:col-1">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Vertical"/>
                <p:spinner id="vertical" value="#{spinnerView.number10}" buttons="vertical"
                           upButtonStyleClass="ui-button-secondary" downButtonStyleClass="ui-button-secondary"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

I've also attempted to use the tabindex property, but the problem still persists. Has anyone experienced this issue with version 10.0.8 of PrimeFaces and found a solution or a way to resolve it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can try running `$('.ui-spinner button.ui-spinner-button').each(function() {this.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1")});` after page is loaded.